# Do 2 conductors (1 grounded via resistor) reach equipotential, before surplus electrons drain to earth?

Tags: resistors, charge, negative, conductors, neutral

Case I: a negative conductor makes contact with a neutral conductor. Negative donates some electrons to neutral, until there is 0 potential difference. Then they both are slightly negative.
This happens quickly. (Assuming they are good conductors.)

[image]
Case II: the neutral conductor is grounded (via a resistor) to earth.
When they make contact, all surplus electrons drain to earth.

How does the resistor affect the movement of electrons?
**Will both conductors reach equipotential first, before surplus electrons
drain to earth?** (Because they make contact with each other without a resistor in between. The resistor is between them and earth.)

Comment: Are you talking about charged conductive plates that have appreciable capacitance to each other and ground?

Comment: @Andyaka Just 2 simple conductors. Like 2 metal rods.

Comment: They will have capacitance to each other and ground and this will dominate an analysis.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Then 2 equally sized pure copper rods.

Answer (score 0):

(Community answer - feel free to improve)

Use the following circuit to simulate what you want to see.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmZskp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No, electrons will not drain to earth after the two conductors reach the same potential.Electrons will go down to earth soon, unless the resistance is very very very high.